# SVG.js, remove/read attribute "transform" from elements imported with "use"

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I am using SVG.js to render a chessboard. The idea is, to keep the pieces in an **external svg-file** `sprite.svg` and include them with [use](http://svgjs.com/elements/#use-constructor), like this:

```
var pieceDrawn = svg.use(piece, "sprite.svg").move(x, y);
```

`piece` may be `wp` white pawn, in the `sprite.svg`:

```
<!-- white pawn //-->    
<g id="wp" transform="translate(225,0)">
    <path d="M 22,9 C 19.79,9 18,[...]"/>
</g>
```

`sprite.svg` was created in Sketch, therefore the group has an attribute `transform`. So when I `move(x,y)` the element, the transformation (255, 0) is added to the moving. How can I read the value of the transformation-attribute or remove it? `pieceDrawn` has no `children()`, `select()` seems not to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found out that

**it is not possible to access attributes from elements included from external files with `use`**

because they are **stored in a [closed Shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931284/what-is-the-difference-between-open-and-closed-shadow-dom-encapsulation-mode)**.

Therefore, yesterday, I wrote a simple utility which can load SVG sprites into the page via XMLHttpRequest, **removes transforms** and unnecessary ids and allows to `use` elements from that sprite in SVGs of the webpage. Like this:

```
let svg = Svg.createSvg(document.getElementById("container"));
Svg.loadSprite("./assets/sprite.svg", ["star", "circle", "triangle", "smiley"]);
Svg.addElement(svg, "use", {"href": "#triangle", x: 10, y: 10});
Svg.addElement(svg, "use", {"href": "#smiley", x: 100, y: 10});
```

You can find it here: https://github.com/shaack/svjs-svg